# SQL Select * Query where sum(col_name) < 500

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want an `SQL Query` which fetches all the records from the table where the `sum` of a particular `column` doesn't exceed 500.

for example :  There is a `dish table` with `dish_name, calorie_value, fat_value, protein_value` as column names. Now I need to fetch all the records from `dish table` where the `sum` of calorie values does not exceed 500.

my current SQL Query :

```
SELECT * FROM dish WHERE SUM(calorie_value) < 500
```

but I am getting invalid use of `group` function.

Comment: Aggregate functions need a group by statement.

Comment: ...and then (in this instance) a HAVING clause instead of a WHERE clause

Answer (score 2):

You need to group your unique field. (i.e. `dish_name` in your case). Then you have to use sub query in case you want to select all fields. Your condition will come in `HAVING` statement.

So your query should be like this:

```
SELECT * FROM dish 
WHERE dish_name IN ( SELECT dish_name FROM dish
                     GROUP BY dish_name
                     HAVING SUM(calorie_value) < 500 )
```

Comment: this query is almost near but when i tested it, i didn't get the desired result.

    another example of the table:

  dish_name                 calorie_value
   phulka                       150
   brown rice                   200
   chapathi                     100
   fried rice                   350
   carrot rice                  150
   jowar onion rotis            200
   aloo parantha                150
   sweet potato chaat           200
   poori                        100

  and now with that condition i shud fetch only the records with total calories of 550 or below

Answer (score 1):

When you say you want to return all the records where the sum of calorie_value doesn't exceed 500 this doesn't really make sense. An individual row in a table can have only one value for calorie_value. So you can use:

```
select * from dish where calorie_value < 500
```

Is this what you need?

Comment: i want all the records with the total calorie of 500 or below